# Update Ledger Table In double entry accounting when there are millions of entries

Tags: mysql, rdbms, dbms

I am creating an double entry accounting software where I have `ledger` table along with other tables. My cash account ledger table for is similar to following:

| ledger_id | ledger_name | ledger_trnx_ammount | ledger_trnx_type | ledger_last_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cash | 500 | dr | 500 |
| 2 | cash | 300 | dr | 800 |
| 3 | cash | 500 | dr | 1200 |
| 4 | cash | 200 | cr | 1000 |
| 5 | cash | 400 | dr | 1400 |
| 6 | cash | 300 | cr | 1100 |

Supose I have edited the entry where `ledger_id` is `2`. I have updated it's `ledger_trnx_ammount` from `300` to `400`, now `ledger_last_balance` should also go up from `800` to `900`. This make following entries inconsistent. To mitigate this issue I have to update all the following entry's `ledger_last_balance` to be consistent with the change like following table:

| ledger_id | ledger_name | ledger_trnx_ammount | ledger_trnx_type | ledger_last_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cash | 500 | dr | 500 |
| 2 | cash | 400 | dr | 900 |
| 3 | cash | 500 | dr | 1300 |
| 4 | cash | 200 | cr | 1100 |
| 5 | cash | 400 | dr | 1500 |
| 6 | cash | 300 | cr | 1200 |

In this table I have updated the entry no. `ledger_id = 2`. To make all the entries last balance consistent I just updated all the following entry's last balance.

This will not be an issue if there are only few entries, but, if there are millions of entries in that table, will updating half the entries or all the entries from that table in this way be efficient? If not, then what should be the approach? Should I redesign the schema or just change the strategy to update the table?

Footnote: I am using MySQL with NodeJS.

Comment: Show us the queries.

Comment: @RickJames I haven't write any queries yet it's my mind mappping

Comment: So, the problem is in whatever changed the the data?

Comment: no the problem is how to change the data @RickJames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ledger systems with double entries you wouldn't normally go back and **change** entries/transactions. This is because each entry is (should be) linked to:

- a receipt
- a bill
- an order
- etc.

...and having one entry in one ledger/book should have a corresponding opposite entry in another ledger/book.

Changing an entry can be considered a crime depending on the country you reside in.

#### What is a double entry ledger system?

> In the double-entry system, transactions are recorded in terms of debits and credits. Since a debit in one account offsets a credit in another, the sum of all debits must equal the sum of all credits. The double-entry system of bookkeeping standardizes the accounting process and improves the accuracy of prepared financial statements, **allowing for improved detection of errors.**

...and...

> For instance, if a business takes a loan from a financial entity like a bank, the borrowed money will raise the company's assets and the loan liability will also rise by an equivalent amount. If a business buys raw material by paying cash, it will lead to an increase in the inventory (asset) while reducing cash capital (another asset). Because there are two or more accounts affected by every transaction carried out by a company, the accounting system is referred to as double-entry accounting.
>
> This practice ensures that the accounting equation always remains balanced – that is, the left side value of the equation will always match with the right side value.

<sup>***Reference:** [Double Entry: What It Means in Accounting and How It's Used](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/double-entry.asp) (investopedia.com)*</sup>

#### Applying to Your Example

Going back and modifying ledger entries might not be the proper way of changing an incorrect entry, because you would have to change two **entries/books/ledgers**. This is because **accounts** have to be in balance:

- Assets
- Liabilities
- Equities
- Revenue
- Expenses
- Gains
- Losses

### Solution 1

In case of a false booking you might have to add an additional entry explaining why the ledger entry is required (and possibly a reference to the incorrect ledger entry) on one side of your books and on the other side you would have to do the same, but the opposite value.

i.e.

#### Cash Assets

In your first book / account you fix the incorrect entry with an additional entry.

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| ledger_id | ledger_name | ledger_trnx_ammount | ledger_trnx_type | ledger_last_balance |          Comment          |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|         7 | cash        |                 100 | dr               |                1300 | correction ledger entry 2 |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

#### Inventory

In your second book / account you deduct the corresponding amount.

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| ledger_id | ledger_name | ledger_trnx_ammount | ledger_trnx_type | ledger_last_balance |          Comment          |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|         7 | inventory   |                 100 | xx               |                300 | correction ledger entry 2 |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

**This way your books are balanced in a double entry ledger system.**

### Solution 2

You could design your double entry ledger system in such a way, that you can't add an amount to a ledger/account, without deducting the same amount from a different ledger/account. This keeps you books in balance.

Answer (score 0):

> if there are millions of entries in that table, will updating an entry from the middle of that table in this way be efficient?

Yes, if the fields you're filtering on in your `WHERE` clause are [indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) properly.

A B-Tree index has a search time complexity of `O(log2(n))` (roughly speaking). That means if your table has 1 million rows, only about `log2(1 million) = 20` nodes in the B-Tree need to be traversed, at max, to find the subset of rows you're looking for. If the table grew to 1 billion rows, then `log2(1 billion) = 30` nodes only. Very trivial numbers for the SQL engine to process.

---

After looking closer at your table, I understand your concern. Typically a field like `ledger_last_balance` is calculated in a view, so the type of update you mentioned doesn't need to modify all of the subsequent rows in realtime. But then there's the tradeoff of it being calculated everytime the view is read from. This requires careful testing and will depend on your use cases (if the view is read from more vs the table being updated more).

In MySQL, you could store the `ledger_last_balance` in a data warehouse type of table instead, which is recalculated every hour / few hours / nightly (whatever frequency is tolerable to the use cases) if it is acceptable for it to be stale periodically.

Comment: it's not about updating only one entry, but after updating one entry I have to update the following entries, if I have millions of entries after that I have to update millions of entries.

Comment: @saimurm360ict I understand. Usually people are concerned about the bottleneck of finding the entries (rows) though, which only is a bottleneck when not indexed properly. If you have 100 million rows in the table, and need to update 1 million of them, so be it. It should be rather quick still, since locating all 1 million will be fast with proper indexing. The time to update 1 million rows is a constant, regardless of how you design your schema. 1 million rows = 1 million rows. But the actual update operation shouldn't take *that* long (assuming your query isn't doing something crazy).